# What is the best place to store the JWT token in the Angular website

Tags: asp.net, angular, jwt, client, token

What is the best place to store the JWT token in the Angular website. I know we can store it in localstorage but that can be easily accessed by JS scripts. I have read so many answers on the google and now I am confused which one to use.

Answer (score 2):

Every place you can store the token in the frontend can be accessed by js scripts.
That being said the most common practices are `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`

- Use `localStorage` when you want the token to persist between tabs and not end the session after browser window is closed
- Use `sessionStorage` when you want the token to be unique to each tab and to be deleted when tab or browser is closed.

You can also store it in cookies or frontend databases as [Kiran mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72413048/3565132)

Answer (score 0):

You can store token at many place it's depend upon your choice basically many developer store token in `local storage` but you have many ways you can try or you can use it.

1. `local storage`

   you can store token in `local storage` but you are telling easily accessed by JS and also you can edit token from `local storage` section under console.

2. `index DB`

   `index Db` is a package in angular which is second option you can use it it provide all function like `set`, `get`, `delete` and so on. the main advantage you cannot edit it's value from console you can try it.

3. `cookies`

   In cookies you can store token but may be it easily accessed by JS.

**I think index DB is a good for storing token and if you want then  you can try it**

Comment: Thanks Kiran, I am familiar with the localstorage and session storage, So I will explore index DB in more detail.